# Furo Sphinx theme uppercases too much in API documentation

Tags: python, themes, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I am a beginner in documentation with Sphinx. I wanted to produce numpy style documentations. Therefore, I used numpydoc extension. Numpy uses `pydata` theme, however I chose `furo`. I understand that there will be some differences in appearance, but I expected my page to have the same format as numpy's at least, though I get the parameter names, and types capitalized. Descriptions are not capitalized.

My docstring:

```py
def translate_pointcloud(pointcloud):
    """
    A data augmentation technique that translates the pointcloud randomly.

    Parameters
    ----------
    pointcloud : numpy.ndarray
    
    See Also
    --------
    rotate_pointcloud, jitter_pointcloud
    """
```

But I have this:
[image]

In my conf.py I use:

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.duration',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'numpydoc',
    ]
html_theme = 'furo'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because of the theme? Is there an easy fix?

Comment: I just switched to pydata theme. It fixed the problem, but it would be nice if it also worked for the 'furo' theme.

Comment: Having `PARAMETERS` in all uppercase seems to be a deliberate style choice (example: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.poolmanager.html). But the names of types and identifiers should be left alone. See also https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/discussions/233.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: The issue has been fixed in Furo 2022.1.2.

---

It's definitely the theme. Probably an oversight, or even a bug, as Furo shouldn't change capitalization of identifiers and types in the API documentation. But it does, [here](https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/blob/fcd6ff66f45f6fb66d26428fe01e9b4a216ffed2/src/furo/assets/styles/content/_api.sass), by applying the CSS property `text-transform: uppercase`.

You can override it with a custom style. In your `docs` folder, create a subfolder `style`, and in it a file `custom.css` with this content:

```css
dl.py .field-list dt {
    text-transform: none;
}
```

(With Furo versions released more recently than when this question was asked, you'll have to use `none !important;` instead of just `none;`. See the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70089196) as to why.)

Then add these two lines to Sphinx's configuration file `conf.py`:

```py
html_static_path = ['style']
html_css_files   = ['custom.css']
```

The rendered output will look something like this:

[image: screenshot]