# Furo Sphinx theme keeps uppercasing too much in API documentation

Tags: themes, python-sphinx, numpydoc

I am facing the same problem discussed in this question: [Furo Sphinx theme uppercases too much in API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873561/furo-sphinx-theme-uppercases-too-much-in-api-documentation/70085598?noredirect=1#comment123892117_70085598). However, the accepted solution did not work, it seems that the Furo template is somehow overwriting the `custom.css`:

[image]

I appreciate any help to implement this simple customization in the [Furo Sphinx theme](https://pradyunsg.me/furo/quickstart/).

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: The issue has been fixed in Furo 2022.1.2.

---

Well, even though the previous question is only a little over two weeks old, there have been five new [releases of Furo](https://pypi.org/project/furo/#history) since then. I will assume you're using the latest version, which is 2021.11.23 as of this writing.

The work-around from the previous answer does in fact no longer work. That's because Furo made the CSS selector more specific in [this commit](https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/commit/8e5f49940eab0c93e5c762a43f05fec215b190b5#diff-8375a7d86372a32d2fec90c68d941fca829dc3e33f20a76d2bdbd9f58d314988), which means [it takes precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841) over the less specific one defined by the custom style.

The `custom.css` therefore needs a little more oomph:

```css
dl.py .field-list dt {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

This keeps being nothing but a work-around, and not necessarily the best one. There should also be a way of only selecting the parameters and types, but leave the "PARAMETERS" heading untouched.

However, the issue is best addressed by Furo's author. I've previously reported it [here](https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/discussions/296), but it has not received a response yet. As I noted there, your other option is to render your NumPy-style doc-strings with [Napoleon](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html) instead of [Numpydoc](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io). They will look different on the page, but the capitalization issue will be gone.

Comment: Thanks @john-hen! The workaround worked but the final result wasn't what I was thinking. We lose the capitalization of the subsections titles (e.g. PARAMETERS, ATTRIBUTES). I'll follow your report on Github.